# FXMLLoader.getController() returns null no matter what

Tags: java, javafx

I have been doing a small app for my studies in JavaFX. In the app, I need to get the controller separately from the Main file, so I've devised this:

```
public class DiceObserver implements Observer {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    public Controller controller = loader.<Controller>getController();

    Dice ov;
    public DiceObserver(Dice dice){
        this.ov = dice;
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        int roll = ov.getLastValue().getRolledValue();
        System.out.println(roll);
        controller.updateBarChart(roll);
    }
}
```

The FXML file:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class Controller{
    @FXML public TextField freqText;
    @FXML public Slider freqSlider;
    @FXML public Button startButton;
    @FXML public Button endButton;
    @FXML public BarChart rollChart;
    @FXML public ImageView dicePic;
    XYChart.Series s1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series s2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series s3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series s4 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series s5 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    XYChart.Series s6 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    Image side1 = new Image("Dice_Side_1.png");
    SimulationThread t = SimulationThread.getInstance();

    public void startSimulation(ActionEvent event) { // start the simulation
        t.start();
    }

    public void getNewFreqValue(ActionEvent event) {
        freqText.setText(String.valueOf(freqSlider.getValue()));
    }

    public void stopSimulation(ActionEvent event) {
        t.end();
    }

    public void updateBarChart(int diceRoll){
        System.out.println(diceRoll);
        int rollval = diceRoll;
        switch (rollval) {
            case 1:
                s1.getData().add(rollval);
                break;
            case 2:
                s2.getData().add(rollval);
                break;
            case 3:
                s3.getData().add(rollval);
                break;
            case 4:
                s4.getData().add(rollval);
                break;
            case 5:
                s5.getData().add(rollval);
                break;
            case 6:
                s6.getData().add(rollval);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void updateDicePic(int diceRoll){
        dicePic.setImage(side1);
    }

    public void initialize() {
    }
}
```

The `updateBarChart` method is in the controller. When I run the code, the loader has a value, but the `getcontroller` method returns null. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns `null` because you have not specified a controller as-of yet. From the code you posted above, your controller and FXML are not aware of each other.

Call:

```
loader.setController(yourControllerInstance);
```

Example:

[image]

https://github.com/SnakeDoc/superD/blob/master/src/com/vanomaly/superd/Main.java#L39

Or you must specify the controller in your FXML document (in your root element):

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="...".... fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <HBox .... >
    ....
```

Example:

[image]

https://github.com/SnakeDoc/Narvaro/blob/master/src/resources/Narvaro.fxml#L13

Answer (score 0):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
public Controller controller = loader.<Controller>getController();
```

You neither set the controller, nor can a controller class specified in the fxml file (`fx:controller` attribute) be initialized, since you do not call [`load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) before using `getController()`.

I guess you're trying to do the latter. However without actually loading the fxml file, no controller will be created. Just creating the `FXMLLoader` instance won't load anything. The input is processed when you call the `load` method. (Processing the input is of course the prerequisite for knowing and thus being able to create the controller instance.)